# zsh: event not found: /filename.py

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, zsh

When I was running my pygame, there is error zsh: event not found: /BreakOut.py
im new to pygame so I don't know what to do
also I used visual studio code
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov1nP.png
any help?

Comment: . represents the current directory in computer language, you coulde add the "." to the front of "/".

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a `.` before your `/`.

Therefore, this is the full command:

```sh
./BreakOut.py
```

(Also, don't forget to add a shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env pythonX` X: Version) on the top of your file and `chmod +x BreakOut.py` to make the file executable)

(Thanks to @ShadowRanger for a better shebang (see comments))

Comment: Slightly more canonical/portable shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env pythonX` (the Windows launcher, `py.exe`, will recognize multiple forms and do the right thing, but on actual UNIX-like systems, it's much more reliable to have `/usr/bin/env` find it in your `PATH` than to assume it's installed in a specific absolute path).